# How to open a file with Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a application in Visual Studio, that runs a external program.

The idea has come into my mind: What if the program i'm trying to run isn't accessible, what would the application do?

How can you generate an error message `msgbox` when running the program fails?
(note that this is VB on 2012 Version).

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Process.Start("C:\Users\{Censored}\Desktop\Bungeecord.bat")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What attempt have you made?  In what way is this not working?  Given the *current code*, what is the behavior when the file isn't accessible?

Comment: Well, i've tried to use "If" but it doesn't fit my codes

Comment: "Doesn't fit"?  Like, there's no *space for it in the file*?  That seems like a *very* arbitrary restriction, and has nothing to do with the actual technical problem at hand.

Comment: Well, I've got more coding to do with that, not only that codes, and not trying to make my code as complex as I can do. I'm trying to show it to my friends to help them too.

Comment: Why the `Sleep`? Do you dislike your users? (that last bit is a joke)

Comment: I'm gonna "refix" that later, that is the temporary code that i'll replace later. lol good joke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use try/catch sentences

```
Try
    [...]
    Process.Start("C:\Users\{Censored}\Desktop\Bungeecord.bat")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Can't access file " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
End Try
```

If you can´t access the file the message will be shown

Comment: This is rather worthless. If the `Process.Start` method throws an exception, then you catch it and display a message. But if you *hadn't* caught the exception, you still would have gotten a message saying an exception had occurred. So it's not really clear what problem you've solved here. Furthermore, it is always bad practice to catch the base `Exception` class, because you'll get exceptions that you should not be swallowing. You need to catch the derived exception class that you actually know how to handle. In this case, it would be either `FileNotFoundException` or `Win32Exception`.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree with your point about only catching these two specific exceptions, but I am wondering about what you mean with *"But if you hadn't caught the exception, you still would have gotten a message"*: I don't think crashing the application as the result of an unhandled exception is equivalent to one method failing cleanly and a message box

Comment: @CodyGray I have given a quickly solution for his problem, I know that it is better to catch the correct exception but it can be unnecessary deppending on the project you are working on and catching whatever exception can be easily changed.